# Как сделать так чтоб не закрывалась программа / С#

Tags: c#

У меня есть консольная программа на C#(калькулятор), после того как выдает результат она закрывается. Как сделать так чтоб завершении она не закрывалась а снова просила ввести что нибудь?

Comment: зациклить? . . .

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: Код посмотреть бы. А так просить вводить можно с помощью Console.Write();

Answer (score 3):

```
while (true) {
  // your existing code

  Console.WriteLine("Do another? (y - for Yes)");
  if (Console.ReadLine() != "y")
    break;
}
```

Comment: Лучше всё-таки спрашивать "хотите посчитать что-нибудь ещё?" с возможностью выхода из цикла при отрицательном ответе.